# REACT state behaviour

Tags: reactjs

i have two states in my react code

1. cityWiseOpenClosedSeries
2. cityWiseOpenClosedSnags

i fetch data from my api and store it in cityWiseOpenClosedSnags and based on cityWiseOpenClosedSnags i create cityWiseOpenClosedSeries. one a certain onClick, i change my cityWiseOpenClosedSeries according to a variable and again cityWiseOpenClosedSnags. this function is also changing my cityWiseOpenClosedSnags to which im not setting state to. any help would be appreciated. Code is pasted below.

```
class ProjectDashboard extends React.Component{

    state = {

        months : [],
        cities : [],
        cityWiseOpenClosedSeries: [],
        cityWiseOpenClosedSnags : []
    }

    openClosedCityClicked = (city) => {
        console.log('on function call', this.state.cityWiseOpenClosedSnags);
        var temp2 = [];
        this.state.cityWiseOpenClosedSnags.forEach(value => {
            if (value.city === city) {
            
                temp2 = [{
                    name: 'open',
                    data: value.openSnags
                }, {
                    name: 'closed',
                    data: value.closedSnags
                }, {
                    name: 'total',
                    data: value.total
                }]

                this.setState({ cityWiseOpenClosedSeries: temp2 });
                
                
            }
        });
        
    }

    render(){

        const cityWiseOpenClosedChartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Snags'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Snags'
                }
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: this.state.months
            },

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            series: this.state.cityWiseOpenClosedSeries,

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
  
      return(
        <div className="project">
             <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={cityWiseOpenClosedChartOptions} containerProps={{ style: { height: "90%", width: "100%" } }} />
             {this.state.cities.map((city, index) => {
                return (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '10px' }} key={index}> {city} <input type="radio" name='city' onClick={() => this.openClosedCityClicked(city)} /></div>  
                );
            })}
            <div style={{ fontSize: '10px' }}> total <input type="radio" name='city' defaultChecked onClick={() => this.openClosedCityClicked('total')} /></div> 
        </div>
      )
    }
  
    componentDidMount(){

        Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL + 'api/snagDashboardInit')
            .then(res => {

                this.setState({ months: res.data.months })
                this.setState({ cities: res.data.cities })
                this.setState({ cityWiseOpenClosedSnags: res.data.cityWiseOpenClosedSnags });

                console.log('init', this.state.cityWiseOpenClosedSnags);

                this.state.cityWiseOpenClosedSnags.forEach(value => {
                    if (value.city === 'total') {
                        let temp = [];
                        temp = [{
                            name: 'open',
                            data: value.openSnags
                        }, {
                            name: 'closed',
                            data: value.closedSnags
                        }, {
                            name: 'total',
                            data: value.total
                        }]
                        this.setState({ cityWiseOpenClosedSeries: temp });
                    }
                });

                //console.log(this.state.posts);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        
    }
  }
  
  export default ProjectDashboard;
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a project in https://codesandbox.io/ so that I can run your code? Thanks.